# build failing on Mac M1 for open ssl ( with killed: 9 error )

Tags: yarnpkg, apple-m1, ocamlbuild, ocaml-dune, esy

I am building an application written in OCaml using yarn and esy. The build process fails trying to build open ssl source code, each time at a random library ( like dsa etc ). For my colleagues using Intel chips, the app builds fine. I am using a mac with m1 chip.

Logs:

```
cc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"~/.esy/3___________________________________________________/s/esy_openssl-93ba2454/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"~/.esy/3___________________________________________________/s/esy_openssl-93ba2454/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/ec/eck_prn.d.tmp -MT crypto/ec/eck_prn.o -c -o crypto/ec/eck_prn.o crypto/ec/eck_prn.c
    cc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"~/.esy/3___________________________________________________/s/esy_openssl-93ba2454/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"~/.esy/3___________________________________________________/s/esy_openssl-93ba2454/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/ec/ecp_mont.d.tmp -MT crypto/ec/ecp_mont.o -c -o crypto/ec/ecp_mont.o crypto/ec/ecp_mont.c
    ***make[1]: *** [crypto/ec/eck_prn.o] Killed: 9***
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[1]: *** [crypto/ec/ecp_mont.o] Killed: 9
    /bin/sh: line 1: 90780 Killed: 9               cmp crypto/ec/ecdsa_sign.d.tmp crypto/ec/ecdsa_sign.d > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    error: command failed: 'make' '-j4' (exited with 2)
    esy-build-package: exiting with errors above...
```

**building esy-openssl@archive:https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz#sha256:0b7a3e5e59c34827fe0c3a74b7ec8baef302b98fa80088d7f9153aa16fa76bd1**

I observed the activity monitor to see the memory usage and also looked at logs in Console.app. Could not find any substantial evidence. Rosetta is turned off.

I am guessing it is a memory issue, tried to see if [upx](https://upx.github.io/) helps - but the binaries are getting cleared from the esy directories.